# Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. You may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, http-redirect, ruby-on-rails-7

When I am changing the page using pagination button or using the scrobble bar in the kanban board card getting DoubleRenderError in Ruby on Rails occurs when I attempt to both render and redirect in the same action of a controller. As the error suggests, you can only call either render or redirect_to once per action

```
  def index
    session[:current_page] = "all_request"
    default_per_page = 15
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || session[:per_page] || default_per_page
    session[:per_page] = @per_page
    @q = ClientRequest.includes(:resource_infos, :developers).page(params[:page]).per(@per_page).ransack(params[:q])
    if (params[:q] && @filter_per_page_value = params[:q][:per_page_eq]) != nil
      @per_page = @filter_per_page_value
      @q = ClientRequest.includes(:resource_infos, :developers).page(params[:page]).per(@per_page).ransack(params[:q])
    end
    @client_requests = @q.result

    kanban_view_details
    render_partials
  end



  def kanban_view_details
    kanban_column_data = KanbanColumn.in_order_of(:name, KanbanViewHelper::KANBAN_COLUMN_ORDER.keys)
    @grouped_kanban_columns = {}
    kanban_column_data.each do |kanban_column|
      custom_sorting_expression, sorted_records = generate_sorted_records(kanban_column)
      pagy, client_requests = pagy_countless(sorted_records, items: 6, page_param: kanban_column.name)
      @grouped_kanban_columns[kanban_column] = [pagy, client_requests]
    end
    load_cache
    @pagy, @kanban_columns = pagy_countless(kanban_column_data, items: 9)
  
    if params[:page]
      render "scrollable_list"
    elsif params[:load]
      render partial: "kanban_views/common_view/common_kanban_page"
    end
  end


  def render_partials
    kanban_view_details
    partial_name = params[:name]
    if partial_name == "classic_view"
      render partial: "classic_views/classic_view"
    elsif partial_name == "kanban_view"
      load_cache
      render partial: "kanban_views/common_view/common_kanban_page", locals: { client_request_cache: @client_request_cache }
    end
  end
```

Comment: It does not appear that you have actually asked a question? You have simply restated the issue that the error is already telling you about. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to resolve the AbstractController::DoubleRenderError and ensure that rendering occurs only once in the ClientRequestsController#index action, even when interacting with the pagination or kanban board.

Comment: Well `index` calls `kanban_view_details` (which calls `render`), `index` also calls `render_partials` which calls `kanban_view_details` (which calls `render`) and `render_partials` calls `render` as well. So the `index` action in theory attempts to call `render` 3 times. It appears that you have conflated rendering from a view perspective and from a controller perspective. To solve this you need to only call render once per action; however, how to achieve you actual goal is unclear since we are not aware of what you are trying to actually do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling render in the kambas and the final render in the index. just change the code to make it to if it render the kambas has a return after to prevent the index return

Comment: Please can you provide an example to validate your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).